# Frequent usage of asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have created an `AsyncTsak` class in my project which downloads some information from web server. I am sure that it works well because when it is called by `onCreate()` , I can see the result . But unfortunately when I call it again via a button it doesn't work.

I am not sure but i think i have read somewhere about this problem . It said , we are permitted to use AsyncTask class only once.

`AsyncTask class`

```
class DownloadAdvertismentLevel2 extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    String [] ImageInformation=null;
    protected void onPreExecute(){          
            // do nothing !             
        }
    protected String doInBackground(String...Urls){
        String Data="";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null; 
        try{
            URL myUrl=new URL("http://10.0.2.2:80/Urgence/ads.aspx?Action=DownloadIds&TB="+TopBoundry+"&LB="+LowBoundry);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)myUrl.openConnection();      
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));         
            String temp=""; 
            // Data is used to store Server's Response 
            while((temp=in.readLine())!=null)
            {               
                 Data=Data+temp;        
            }    
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.d("Er>doInBackground", ex.toString());
            urlConnection.disconnect(); 
        }
        finally{
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return Data;// it sends Result to onPostExcute 
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String Data){
            createPhotoAlbum();
            pb.closedProg();
            }           
        }
```

`onCreate`

Here I don't have any problem . It works fine

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ads);       
        new DownloadAdvertismentLevel2().execute();
    }
```

`Via Button`

```
 ButtonSeeMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  Counting();  
              }});
```

`Counting`

```
 public void Counting(){
            if(TotalRows-6>0){
                TopBoundry=TotalRows;
                LowBoundry=TotalRows-6;
                TotalRows=LowBoundry;
                }   
            new DownloadAdvertismentLevel2().execute();
        }
```

Please consider that I need to use this class till it shows the information. What would you suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I think you might be able to use the Async task only once in the class. But definitely it can be called multiple times.

2) please check if your button `onclicklistener()` function is really getting called on button click. try some logs in that.

because the code seems to be fine.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what JVN said about AsyncTask

Each instance of Async task can only be executed once.

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html (Under 'Threading Rules')

This doesn't stop you making a new instance -

```
public void Counting(){
            if(TotalRows-6>0){
                TopBoundry=TotalRows;
                LowBoundry=TotalRows-6;
                TotalRows=LowBoundry;
                }   
            new DownloadAdvertismentLevel2().execute();
            new DownloadAdvertismentLevel2().execute();
        }
```

^ The code above will run your task twice.

Your code looks fine.
I would guess that the problem is (in order of likelihood)

1) On click isn't working

2) Post Execute isn't working as expected

3) The server response isn't being read correctly

4) Your Server isn't handling the request properly

- But this would be obvious if you run your debugger or add some extra log outputs

Answer (score 0):

To allow multiple asycnh tasks run at the same time you need to use the 'executeOnExceuter mechanism:

See this note from the Android doucmentation:

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

An example invocation would look like (this particular example is from a video manipulation app - the 'distributionTask' is an instance of a class that extends AsynchTask):

```
//Now execute synch task - to allow multiple AsynchTasks execute in parallel the 
//'executeOnExecutor' call is required. It needs to be used with caution to avoid the usual synchronization issues and also 
//to avoid too many threads being created
distributionTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/videoChunk_"+i+".mp4");
```